# How to implement common method in php?

Tags: function, class, abstract, entities

How to implement a method in a class that can be used by everyone users in php ?
My idea is not to repeat the implementation of readsales in each of the entities

i have 3 users:

admin  readSales function,
manager readSales function,
employee, insertSale AND  readSales function

Is it possible to implement common methods in a single class? And then call each of the methods to the daughter classes?

```
 abstract class commonMethods {

 abstract readSales() {

   $pdo = new PDO();
     //statements
     //readSales
     //return $list;
   }

  }



 class Manager extends commonMethods {

  function readSales(){
    return readSales();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible, what you need is either a trait or an abstract class.
Here's an example with Abstract class :

```
<?php

/**
 * The abstract class
 */
abstract class CommonMethods
{

    public function readSales(){
        // Your code
    }

    public function hello(){
        echo "Hello";
    }

}

/**
 * The Class
 */
class Manager extends CommonMethods
{
    // No need to add the "readSales" or "hello" method
    // Since we had extended them

    public function world(){
        echo "World";
    }

}

$Manager = new Manager;
$Manager->readSales(); // Works!
$Manager->hello(); // Output: "Hello"
$Manager->world(); // Output: "World"

// The final output: "HelloWorld"
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php